# Is it possible to group Tumblr posts by day?

Tags: html, tumblr

Is it possible to hack the date tag on a Tumblr page to display posts like this:

**Today**

- Post 1
- Post 2
- Post 3

**Yesterday**

- Post 4
- Post 5
- Post 6

**Monday**

- Post 7
- Post 8
- Post 9

'Today' and 'Yesterday' can be replaced by 'Wednesday' and 'Tuesday' if need be.

Comment: Could you not use: `{DayOfWeek}` iirc day pages use the same theme helpers as `date`: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#dates

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. That adds the day of the week but for each post. What I'm looking to do is group them, so the day only shows once then all of the posts from that day are listed below.

Comment: Maybe use CSS to hide the repeated dates? If you can add either the template or html I am happy to look at the CSS part.

Answer (score 0):

Tumblr's templating does not contemplate grouping. The only way to do it is to manually (i.e. via javascript) group the posts and create headlines between each group.

Assuming jQuery for brevity:

```
var days = {};

//group posts by day
$('.post').each(function (i, el) {
    //get timestamp from post
    var timestamp = new Date($(el).data('timestamp')*1000);

    //set to midnight of day
    timestamp.setHours(0,0,0,0);

    //create array for each day if it doesn't already exist
    days[timestamp] = days[timestamp] || [];

    days[timestamp].push(el);
});

//now "days" will be an array of days each containing an array of posts
//print the day of the week above the first post of each day
var dayNames = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
$.each(days, function (dayTimestamp, dayPosts) {
    //create headline with day of the week in it
    var $h = $('<h1>').text(dayNames[dayTimestamp.getDay()]);

    //add it before the first post of the day
    $h.insertBefore(dayPosts[0]);
});
```

And in your template, make sure you have this for each post:

```
<div class="post" data-timestamp="{Timestamp}">...content...</div>
```

Untested code but it should get you started